# phpMyAdmin ErrorCode: 13 Can't get stat of './test'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 11.04 Natty with a fresh installation of LAMP and phpMyAdmin. I have set the root account on MySQL with a password, and when I log in to phpMyAdmin as root and try to create a database (called "test"), I get the following error:

```
#13 - Can't get stat of './test' (Errcode: 13)
```

After some research, this appears to be a permissions issue, however I am logged in as root, so I'm not sure why this would be happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by moving the file to /tmp/test and used LOAD DATA INFILE...

If you use php and you have upload a file from a form, maybe you could use to get the complete its path and (temp) name with the variable: $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"]

Answer (score 0):

Got it with:

```
sudo dolphin
```

Changed folder permissions in /var/lib/mysq to 777 (**not recommended for production servers!**): right click mysql folder -> properties -> permissions tab -> change "Group" and "Others" to "Can View & Modify Content" -> check "Apply changes to all subfolders and their contents" checkbox -> OK.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

Navigate to the XAMPP config folder

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/
```

Set permissions of `my.cnf` to `600`

```
sudo chmod 600 my.cnf
```

Restart MySQL